# How to change from react router flux too react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I have just began to learn react native however id like to add drawer navigator for the application however I do not know how I would be able to implement it into my current app. Any changes to go towards react-navigation have just broken it beyond repair. Im currently using react native router flux for navigating however there seems to be no drawer option for this method that I can find.

Is there a tutorial or simple method of adding a navigation drawer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the drawer that comes with the **react-native-router-flux**
and then use it as below:

```
<Drawer hideNavBar key="drawer" contentComponent={Sidebar} drawerIcon={() => <Icon name="menu" size={30} color="#900"/>} drawerWidth={300}>
   <Scene key="root">
     <Scene key="Welcome" component={Welcome} hideNavBar initial afterLogin={() => Actions.Experts()} />

   </Scene>
</Drawer>
```

after that you can create a component named Sidebar